# React Native Images with URI not displaying on device

Tags: react-native

I have a tile type list with squares that show images.  I am using a basic react  component and setting the URI from a data source I am pulling into state.

The images display perfectly on a android emulator but as soon as I run this on a device, the images do not display.

All of my image sources are set using the below and all URLS are https.

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={ {uri: contact.sProfilePicLink} } />
```

Any one have any idea why? I have tried 3 different devices.

Below are my react native details:

React Native: 0.57.7
React Native CLI: 2.0.1

**SOLVED**

I found the problem. Completely my fault. There was something wrong with the domain where I was trying to fetch the images from. They must of been cached on the simulators, thats why they were working and on any new device it was not working. SORRY

Comment: all looks good, but to be sure. are you add `size` (width and height) inside `styles.image`?

Comment: I wasn't. I only had flex 1. I have changed it to have the width and height hard coded in the style prop but it is still not displaying ... <Image style={[styles.image, {width: 50, height: 50}]} source={ {uri: contact.sProfilePicLink}} />

Comment: I found the problem. Completely my fault. There was something wrong with the domain where I was trying to fetch the images from. They must of been cached on the simulators, thats why they were working and on any new device it was not working. SORRY

Answer (score 0):

its all in your style 
try to give the width or hieght to your image

Comment: Hi, no, it wasn't this. I found the problem. Completely my fault. There was something wrong with the domain where I was trying to fetch the images from. They must of been cached on the simulators, thats why they were working and on any new device it was not working. SORRY